# Javascript deleting wrong elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the code over at Paste Bin @ http://pastebin.com/bu2sz2C0. I have been given this code as an academic assignment and is not code i have written myself with the exception of the killFrog function.

The issue I am having is with the killFrog function. Each frog is stored in an Array called Frogs and then the DOM elements representing these frogs are stored as _frogs. I am trying to make it so that when you click the Kill Frog button the killFrog function is triggered and deletes a random frog from the Array, and then removes that Frog from the DOM.

Using console.log() I have found the ID of the frog and the attribute "data-frogid" of the frog and is outputting correctly which of the frogs should be removed from the DOM however, sometimes it removes the correct frog from the dom, sometimes the wrong frog or sometimes not at all. I am baffled by this as it is outputting to the console which frog should be removed but then not removing the correct one.

Here is the code I have written for killFrog

```
killFrog = function(){
          console.log('////////////Selected Frog to Die///////////////');
          var _randomFrog = this.Frogs[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.Frogs.length)];
          console.log(_randomFrog);
          var indexOfFrog = this.Frogs.indexOf(_randomFrog);
          this.Frogs.splice(indexOfFrog,1); //Remove frog from array
          console.log(_frogs.childNodes);
          console.log("ID of FROG to be deleted" + _randomFrog.getId());
          for (var i = 0; i < _frogs.childNodes.length; i++) {
             if (_randomFrog.getId() == _frogs.childNodes[i].getAttribute("data-frogid")){
                console.log("ID : " + _randomFrog.getId() +  " Data attribute : " + _frogs.childNodes[i].getAttribute("data-frogid") + " NAME: " + _randomFrog.name + " DOM eleement name : " + _frogs.childNodes[i].innerHTML + " To be removed");
                // _frogs.removeChild(_frogs.childNodes[i]);
                _frogs.childNodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(_frogs.childNodes[i]);
             }
          };
          console.log(this.Frogs.length + "Frogs left in the array");
      },
```

Update:

Code updated to remove duplicate i variable @ http://pastebin.com/4JiQBK12

I believe this is due to the way the Id's are set on the array of Frogs. From the code i have updated, when I display the data attribute of the frog it does not correspond with the ID that it gets from the Array.

could this be the way that the id's are set for the frogs at

```
frog.setId(this.Frogs[this.Frogs.length - 1] ? this.Frogs[this.Frogs.length - 1].getId() + 1 : 1);
```

Comment: If you watch the console, you'll notice that the id of the frog to be deleted is sometimes an id of a frog that has already been deleted. When that happens, no frog is removed from the ui (however it is removed from the array)

Comment: Yep I noticed that, Im not sure how to move forward though as I cant understand why the ID's dont match up.

Comment: I'm kinda confused as to what the point of the frog having an id to begin with is. The id seems to be where the problem is originating, but the id isn't something that is set by the frog constructor at all, it's decided by the pond. I would consider linking the dom element related to the frog to the Frog so that you can easily gain reference to it to remove it.

Comment: The thing is, when the frog is originally created and i log to the console the ID, they are fine, but when i loop through the array of frogs and get their ID, they arent correct.

Comment: Ok, lets take this from the beginning. First, identify a pattern. The pattern i see is only the most recently added frog is ever removed. Ok, so, how is it that the last frog is the one that is always *randomly* chosen? and why is it chosen *again* even after it is removed?

Comment: I really don't know :/ Ive put code on http://pastebin.com/Qk1YxWDv, to demonstrate that, if it ever gets 'Frank' its id is 2 despite being originally being 1 when it is added.

Comment: Right, but i'm working through the debugging process with you, just make sure that you're seeing what i'm seeing as i work through it.

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying :) Im just really baffled how the getID() changes once its put into an array

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bqBT/ I added a reference to frogPond to window so i can access it in the console. Right off the bat, i see a problem. After grabbing all frogs and the logging the id of each frog, all frogs have the same id! how is that possible. both Frank and Georgia have an id of 2.

Comment: I was just about to say I just did _randomFrog = this.Frogs[0] and the _randomFrog.getId() shows as 2? but when its added, it has the id of 1?

Comment: When you add a 3rd frog, they all have the id "3"

Comment: Do you think its an issue with how the ID's are set?

Comment: I see... all of your frogs are using the same private _id variable. :) I didn't catch it at first because i've never seen the revealing pattern used to define a prototype. Maybe this is why.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by the private _id variable, i didnt know you could have private variables in javascript?

Comment: well, it's private in that it's defined in a scope that makes it unavailable everywhere other than within that scope. the fact that it's *private* is irrelevant though.

Comment: The problem here is the way that you are populating the prototype. The pond suffers from the same problem.

Comment: hmm, i'm really not sure how to progress with this then as I've never looked into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the revealing pattern to set your prototype, all instances of Frog (and Pond) are using the same data. For example, if you set the id of frog 1 to 5, frog 2's id will also be 5. Here's a simplified example of what you have:

```
function foo () {}
foo.prototype = function () {
    var _id = 5;
    return {
        getId: function() {
            return _id;
        },
        setId: function(id) {
            _id = id
        }
    }
}();
var foo1 = new foo();
var foo2 = new foo();
foo1.setId(1);
console.log(foo2.getId()); //1
foo2.setId(8);
console.log(foo1.getId()); //8
```

To solve this, don't use the revealing pattern to define the prototype. There are several ways, what i've shown below is just one of them.

```
function foo () {
    var _id = 0;
    this.getId = function() {
        return _id;
    };
    this.setId = function(id) {
        _id = id
    };
}
var foo1 = new foo();
var foo2 = new foo();
foo1.setId(1);
console.log(foo2.getId()); //0
foo2.setId(8);
console.log(foo1.getId()); //1
```

Comment: Thank you very much and it seems this does work however for the assignment I do have to stick to using the prototypes etc. Is there any way to do this whilst still using the revealing pattern?

Comment: Not in a meaningful way, however, you can still use the prototype. i'll update

Comment: actually, nevermind. If you do move to using the prototype, your getters and setters no longer make sense, making the prototype relatively useless in this case.

Comment: Why is it that the getters and setters don't make sense?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Rz7p/1/ to use the prototype, the variable has to be part of the instance, making it available directly. Why have `Frog.getId()` when you can directly access it as `Frog.id`. You can still add birth to the prototype, but i don't see a purpose for even having it, you can accomplish the same thing directly in the constructor.

Comment: I suggest either using the revealing pattern, or the constructor pattern. not both.

Comment: If you switched to using the prototype such as here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Rz7p/2/ every place where you would use `.setId(5)` you would also be able to use `.id = 5`

Comment: Im still not really sure whats going on but thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Ive tried to change this to http://jsfiddle.net/WNvHg/ but now will not run at all?

Comment: My real question is that, using the revealing pattern on its own, how could the desired functionality be implemented?

Comment: I'm actually working on that, here's a little bit of a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3bqBT/8/ It wold likely have been easier to do it from scratch, because now i'm having to find all the places where it's still using the constructor pattern

Comment: If possible, briefly I am very appreciative of what you have done for me, can you walk me through the changes, also to confirm.. is this fiddle in the revealing pattern? Also can you recommend any Javascript pattern books or articles to read from? I have implemented some before in Java such as Observer but have never looked into them on Javascript. Thank you so much.

Comment: The biggest change was i replaced the constructors with the revealing functions you were using to create the prototypes. I then replaced all incorrect references to `this`, and removed any place where you were testing instanceOf since that doesn't work when you aren't using constructors.

Comment: Here is a good read on javascript design patterns: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: Cool. i thought of a purpose for using both revealing and constructor together. http://jsfiddle.net/6Rz7p/4/ an auto incrementing id using a *"private"* variable that is shared among all instances. You can use this to store anything that would need to be the same for all instances, such as an array of all instances so you could do `frog.getAllFrogs()`, but you'll have to also have a `frog.die()` to remove it from that private array.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the `i` variable twice in the same scope:

```
var i = this.Frogs.indexOf(_randomFrog);
```

and

```
for (var i = 0; i < _frogs.childNodes.length; i++) {
```

Variables should always be declared at the top of the scope. Hoisting and overwriting can cause a lot of confusion, like this.

For this situation, the vars should not be named the same.

Comment: Ahh dear, I have changed this however this is still acting in the same way.

Comment: Well you can't just change the variable name, you also need to make sure the rest of the code is referencing the newly named var.